# python memory usage keep increasing when using asyncio semaphore

Tags: python, python-asyncio, semaphore

If I remove the semaphore, the script works well, no obvious memory usage increasing during the running time.

I suspect that the tasks are keep appending in somewhere while I limited the number of concurrency. How should I solve this? or should I refactor the whole structure?

```
import asyncio


async def task(acc_id, semaphore):
    async with semaphore:
        print(f"acc_id {acc_id} received the task")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print(f"acc_id {acc_id} finished the task")


async def create_tasks(event_loop, acc_id):
    # limit the concurrent tasks per acc
    semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(2)
    while True:
        event_loop.create_task(task(acc_id, semaphore))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # request per 0.01 sec


async def create_tasks_for_all_accs(event_loop):
    for acc_id in range(3):
        event_loop.create_task(create_tasks(event_loop, acc_id))


def main():
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(create_tasks_for_all_accs(event_loop))
    event_loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're creating tasks every .01 seconds and only allowing 6 to run at a time each of which takes 5 seconds. This is causing all your tasks that are blocked on the semaphore to wait for a slot to free up, so its no surprise that memory increases, you're creating tasks faster than you can process them with the semaphore. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you need thousands of tasks running concurrently as you have now, or is six tasks total fine? Without understanding what you're trying to accomplish it is hard to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the actual function `task` takes much less time than that.
and my goal is limit the number of currency by semaphore. The function create_tasks should be paused if the semaphore value is greater than 2.